# Spring mvc : Changing default Response format from xml to json

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have gone through other similar asked questions but nothing worked for me.

All my **API's return JSON** as response **by Default**:

Because of some XML API,  i had to add jackson-xml

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

**Now** by default "**Without accept header" All responses are XML**.

I would like to have **JSON as default Response format** .

As stated in the doc here:

https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

I implemented the following config :

```
@Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false).favorParameter(true).parameterName("mediaType").ignoreAcceptHeader(true)    
                .useJaf(false).defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }
```

**Case 1:** if i make the `ignoreAcceptHeader(true)`    then everything is JSON even the XML API returning JSON.

**Case 2:** when `ignoreAcceptHeader(false)` is then default is XML.

I forget to mention my API's look like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getXml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<String> getXml( HttpServletRequest request)
        throws JAXBException {
    return returnXml();
}
```

I am quite lost here, All i want is Default(Without AcceptHeader) should be JSON.  (API returns XML as String)

And when Accept Header : "Application/xml" is defined then response should be XML.

Any advice would be of great help.

Thanks.

Comment: According to configuration you can control return media type with 'mediaType' parameter. Did you try something like /getXml?mediaType=xml

Comment: @Stan : no i cannot change the RequestMapping but still  i will try it to see the results

Comment: It's not about request mapping annotation, as I understood you are saying to Spring with .parameterName("mediaType") statement to check media type using this parameter so there are no changes on your server side

Comment: @Stan : it worked :) :) but then i have to communicate new URL to customer? or i can manipulate the URL once i recieve the request ?

Comment: @Stan : if i am not wrong, then adding something like response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);  in API would be same right ?

Comment: Not sure it will be the same since haven't seen how Spring handles that. Another option if you have fixed endpoints for XML you can probably add "produces" attribute to RequestMapping annotation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general if you want to get json response you need an jackson-databind module:

```
<dependency> 
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId> 
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId> 
    <version>${json-jackson-version}</version> 
</dependency>
```

and then you have to define a `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` in your configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebAppMainConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override 
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) { 
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        [..] 
        super.configureMessageConverters(converters); 
    }

    [...]
}
```

In your case, you can implement your own [AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter.html) so you can switch in this converter between different concrete converters depending on media type.

Check the method  `AbstractGenericHttpMessageConverter#writeInternal(..)`

Answer (score 8):

For me, adding

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8);
    }

}
```

solved the problem.

Now by default all `RestController`s return JSON, if no `Accept` header in the request.
Also if `Accept: application/xml` header is passed, then result is XML.

Also, worth reading: https://spring.io/blog/2013/05/11/content-negotiation-using-spring-mvc

Comment: Just a detail: in a Spring boot application, your `@Configuration` classes should not contain the `@EnableWebMvc` annotation ([source](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-enablewebmvc-and-common-use-cases)). It may prevent other things from working, such as the springfox-swagger-ui html page.

Comment: @PauloMerson Yes, you are totally right! I'll remove this from the answer to prevent confuse any readers, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As you have set ignoreAcceptHeader to true and favorPathExtension to false, spring will rely on other alternatives for content negotiations. Means it will look URL parameter which you have configured XML and JSON

so as @stan pointed `/getXml?mediaType=xml` will should return xml response else it will default to `json(defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))`

Comment: thanks for your response, but i am already doing something like this : contentTypeList.add(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE);
   headers.put("Content-Type", contentTypeList); and i expect it to send XML without "?mediatype=xml"

Comment: but this is not happening.