# "status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, post, mime-types

I have following controller:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/test/set_timeout"})
    @ResponseBody
    public void setAlertTimeout(@RequestBody Long timeout) {
```

and I make following request in postman:
[image]

text from error:

```
{"timestamp":1495560868392,"status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media Type","exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Content type 'multipart/form-data;boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary9IbVq5JAKxCYUs7P;charset=UTF-8' not supported","path":"/test/set_timeout"}
```

What the reason of the problem and how to send request correct?

P.S.

If to use

```
public static class LongWrapper{
        private long timeout;

        public long getTimeout() {
            return timeout;
        }

        public void setTimeout(long timeout) {
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }
    }
```

instead of Long and pass json(`{"timeout":"2"}`) - it works correct

Comment: Please Check this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753357/http-status-415-post-json-data-to-spring-mvc-4-using-ajax-also-used-spring-sec?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

When reading json your content type should be application/json.

Comment: Where do you see json?

Answer (score 0):

if you need to use application/json type and write below code in controller method :-

```
   @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
    public RestResponse save(@RequestParam("timestamp") String timestamp, @RequestParam("status") String status) {
```

Comment: I want use body

Comment: Why do you think I want to use json?

Comment: use `RequestBody`

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestBody` is used to deserialize `JSON` to `POJO`. If you need to submit form data to the controller try something like

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/test/set_timeout"})
@ResponseBody
public void setAlertTimeout(HttpServletRequest request) {
   Long l = request.getParameter("timeout");
   // continue
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your request you are sending the timeout property in a multipart/form-data body.
In postman, select option 'raw' for the body and set the content type to application/json. Then enter the following as body content:

```
{timeout: 4}
```

You should also set the consumes MediaType on your controller. (Although it could be that it automatically resolves to json) For example:

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/test/set_timeout"}, consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add a content-type header manually. You are overriding the value set by Postman. Just select form-data in POST request and send your request to see if it works.